# Swift combine chain requests

Tags: swift, combine

<strike>I'm attempting to use combine to chain two requests together. The code is pretty rough, but I need to call two api requests. One to get the schedule data than one for live data. I'm able to get the live data *(second request)* but how do I get the schedule data *(first request)*? I'm having a hard time understanding how to use combine to chain two requests together, this is my first need to use combine for a widget I'm working on. I'm still fresh to Swift, so my terminology may be lacking.</strike>

My last code example wasn't correct and my question was unclear. I have two `publishers` and the *second one* depends on the *first one*. My understanding is still unclear on how to handle the data from my first `publisher` as well as in `.flatMap` for the second data. Does it need to be `ObservableObject` class and have `@Published` variables for the data? Do I use `.assign` or `.sink` to get data from my codable data `Schedule` and `Live`? Articles seem a bit too advance for myself as they create custom `extensions` and changing the API data to `nested types`.

New example code

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class DataGroup {
    // How to get data from Schedule and Live codable data, do I use a variable and .assign or .sink?
    // Where do I put the subscriber?
    
    func requestSchedule(_ teamID : Int) -> AnyPublisher<Schedule, Error> {
        let url = URL(string: "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?teamId=\(teamID)")!
        return URLSession
            .shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: Schedule.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .flatMap {self.fetchLiveFeed($0.dates.first?.games.first?.link ?? "")}
            /*
            .flatMap {URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: $0.dates.first?.games.first?.link ?? "")!)}
            */
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    

    // Remove and put into flatMap URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher?
    func fetchLiveFeed(_ link: String) -> AnyPublisher<Live, Error> {
        let url = URL(string: "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com\(link)")!
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: Live.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

OLD

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class CombineData {
    var schedule: Schedule? // Get schedule data alongside live data
    var live: Live?
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func fetchSchedule(_ teamID: Int, _ completion: @escaping (/* Schedule, */Live) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?teamId=\(teamID)")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: Schedule.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .flatMap { self.fetchLiveFeed($0.dates.first?.games.first?.link ?? "") }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }) { data in
                // How to get both schedule data and live data here?
                //self.schedule = ?
                self.live = data
                print(data)
                completion(self.schedule!, self.live!)
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func fetchLiveFeed(_ link: String) -> AnyPublisher<Live, Error> {
        let url = URL(string: "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com\(link)")!
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: Live.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do you need to chain them together, is the input to one method coming from the published data of the other?

Comment: Yes, the first one gets data for the second request. My question is how do I get both data from the first and second request. The data is being called fine for the second request but I'm unsure how to store or reference the first request's data.

Comment: I still don’t fully understand how they are connected but for starters I would try to rewrite or break out the publishing part of fetchSchedule so it ends with .flatMap and returns AnyPublisher and then find a suitable operator to combine the two publishers. I write "try to" because I don’t know if it is the right solution but it looks like a good way forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to use a `flatMap` for chaining, which is what you did, but if you also need the original value, you can return a `Zip` publisher (with a `.zip` operator)  that puts two results into a tuple.

One of the publishers is the second request, and the other should just emit the value. You can typically do this with `Just(v)`, but you have to make sure that its failure type (which is `Never`) matches with the other publisher. You can match its failure type with `.setFailureType(to:)`:

```
publisher1
   .flatMap { one in
       Just(one).setFailureType(to: Error.self) // error has to match publisher2
         .zip(publisher2(with: one))
   }
   .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        // ...
    }, receiveValue: { (one, two) in
        // ...
    })
```

Alternatively, you can use `Result.Publisher` which would infer the error (but might look somewhat odd):

```
.flatMap { one in
   Result.Publisher(.success(one))
      .zip(publisher2)
}
```

---

So, in your case it's going to be something like this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
   .map(\.data)
   .decode(type: Schedule.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
   .flatMap {
       Result.Publisher(.success($0))
          .zip(self.fetchLiveFeed($0.dates.first?.games.first?.link ?? ""))
   }
   .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        // ...
    }, receiveValue: { (schedule, live) in
        // ...
    })
   .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples but can't seem to get it working still. Using both methods.

Comment: @cole, what does "can't seem to get it working" mean? Are there errors?

Comment: `.flatMap { $0 in Result.Publisher(.success($0)) .zip(self.fetchLiveFeed($0.dates.first?.games.first?.link ?? "")) }`  I get `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'`. Then If I remove the $0 in I get a bunch of errors also.

Comment: Oh.. it was a minor typo - fixed // @cole

Comment: That works but I can't assign the data inside `.sink` like in my example. Also I don't fully understand how that is suppose to assign the data for schedule my first variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. Inside the `sink` you would get a tuple e.g. `.sink { (schedule, live) in ... }` - see the top example

Comment: I'm now getting `Missing argument for parameter 'receiveValue' in call` then `Contextual closure type '(Subscribers.Completion<Error>) -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body`.

Comment: I've updated the answer. When publisher's failure is not `Never`, you have to use `sink(receiveCompletion:receiveValue:)`